# why is my BLE scanner didnt spot any device although i have apply location request?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm kinda new here and right now i'm trying to set up a basic BLE scanner app but the app does not spot my BLE module (im using the basic code on android development page).

i have try to look up online for solution and found out that the problems was the location requirement. However even after i apply this request i still cant find my BLE module

```
this is the location request 
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                } else {
                    // Alert the user that this application requires the location permission to perform the scan.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my scanning code

```
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                    mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you also add permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** ?
It'll look like

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Meanwhile, you need go to setting in your cell somewhere in **Application**.

Find your own Android app and then give it location permission.

Hope it help.